# Vectorizing a Large 2D Dataframe for optimx L-BFGS-B efficiency

Tags: r

I am reasonably new to R and more advanced statistical methods and am trying to use it to replace a max log likelihood optimization process that formerly used SAS.  Effectively I am trying to optimize about 100 +/- variables over several thousand equations.  Also, even though there ~ 100 variables, for any given equation most of them are not used.  So, my input (mu) would look something like below with 1000's of columns and upward of a 100 rows.  In the equation below we are optimizing for the u's with k being the value in the matrix mu (exponent k in the equation).

[image]

```
X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9  X10  X11 ...Xm
0   0   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0    0      0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0      0
0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0    0      0
0   0   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0    0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0    0      0
.
.
.
```

My target function is as follows (n_t = nrow and n_d nColumn) and each equation results in a 1 or a 0 (entity is good or bad)

```
f_prb <- function(mu) {
        y <- 0
        for(j in 1:n_d) {
          tmp_val <- 1
          for(i in 1:n_t) {
            tmp_val <- tmp_val*(mu[i]**k_mat[i,j])
          } 
          y <- y+x[j,1]*log(tmp_val)+(1-x[j,1])*log(1-tmp_val)
        }
        y <- -y
      }
```

With initial estimates being in PsCurrent$Ps and upper and lower bounds of 0.1 and 0.99 (all u must be  < 1 and > 0) I am using optimx L-BFGS-B for maximum likelihood (I've also tried Nelder-Mead).  The way the function is set up is very slow to say the least.

```
rst <- optimx(PsCurrent$Ps,f_prb,lower=lb,upper=ub,method="L-BFGS-B")
```

Doing some research I found that there are likely better ways in R to formulate the function to make it much faster. Specifically [this reference](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2011/06/18/speeding-up-mle-code-in-r/) shows a marked improvement.  Unfortunately, my programming skills in R don't lead me to translate how to put my function in one of the faster formats and I was hoping that I might get some insight from an expert in this forum (I'm sure I'll get a Duh! moment).  Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work this out piecewise for a result that I am happy with.  For information, I originally started with a Nelder-Mead implementation in dfoptim because it was a bounded optimization.  For my test example this was taking right at 24 hrs to complete.  When I switched to L-BFGS-B in optimx the same implementation went down to about 8 hours.  With the vectorization below I was able to get it down to 22 minutes.

My new objective function is:

```
      f_prb <- function(mu) {
        #apply exponent to survival estimates
        kMatExp <- mu ** k_mat

        #calculate the product of the columns
        kMatProd <- apply(kMatExp,2,prod)

        #take log of the results
        kMatProdLog <- log(kMatProd)

        #set up the inverse values
        kMatProdInv <- 1 - kMatProd
        kMatProdInvLog <- log(kMatProdInv)
        xInv <- 1 - x

        #combine inverse and non inverse survival estimates
        kMatFinal <- x * kMatProdLog + xInv * kMatProdInvLog

        #get the sum of the estimates
        y <- -sum(kMatFinal$gb)
      }
```

Note in this that the vector x is the resultant survival (1 or 0) and mu is the vector of values being optimized for.